# Is it possible to use TimeSpan.TryParseExact for times with hundreds of minutes (format ~ "mmm:ss")?

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan, format-string

Rather than writing a couple of lines to parse out the time manually, divide by 60, and put everything together, is there a format that would allow TimeSpan.[Try]ParseExact to read out a time such as "123:45"?

The following code suggests that parsing fails when the format string is @"mm:ss" but I've also tried @"m:ss" and @"mmm:ss" to no avail.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var culture = default(CultureInfo);
        var timeString = "123:45";
        if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeString, @"mm\:ss", culture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out var time))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{time.Hours}:{time.Minutes}:{time.Seconds}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such format, as [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) detail ("the number of whole minutes in the time interval that isn't included as part of its hours or days component"). `TimeSpan` is not very flexible.

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks Jeroen.